# How to add Objective-c static lib into Swift Framework?

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks, static-libraries

I'm writing a Cocoa Framework for iOS in Swift language. I need to add Objective-c static library inside this framework.

i referred - https://medium.com/swift-and-ios-writing/using-a-c-library-inside-a-swift-framework-d041d7b701d9

and follow the all the steps but not able to access the objective c library functions.

Getting Error -

could not build Objective-C module <'Framework_Name'>

<'HeaderFileName.h'> file not found

Comment: try if this helps
https://medium.com/@yuliiasynytsia/link-static-c-library-to-swift-framework-as-a-private-module-97eae2fec75e

Comment: Hey, welcome to the stack overflow. Could you please outline what you have already tried and what gone wrong?